# How to set domain name in CentOS 6.6.

Tags: linux, centos-6

I am using CentOS 6.6

This is my `/etc/sysconfig/network` file

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=rahul
```

This is my `/etc/hosts` file entry

`172.16.11.222   rahul.example.com   rahul`

If I type `hostname` I will get this output

`rahul`

if I type `hostname -f` I will get this

`rahul.example.com`

But If I type `domainame` I will get this

`(none)`

I to set domain name ?

Answer (score 1):

The `domainname` command is related to NIS, which is long, long obsoleted. Don't try to rely on that command. The `hostname` command is enough. What you have done is enough also.

I recommend that you set the FQDN in the `HOSTNAME` line also.

Comment: How to set FQDN ? in my case.

Comment: Exactly what you're expecting... rahul.example.com...

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 6.2:

/etc/hosts

```
192.168.1.62 host62.example.com host64
...
```

Just setting /etc/hosts with FQDN first, followed by hostname without domain should be sufficient for 'hostname -s|-d|-f' to return host62|example.com|host64.

/etc/resolv.conf is overwritten by NetworkManager using values returned by your DHCP server on reboot:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain ...
search ...
nameserver ...
nameserver ...
```

Note that 'domain ...' appears to be ignored by 'hostname'.